# React mixin to composition refactor

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After I read how bad mixins are and made some bad experiences by myself, I want to refactor my code to use composition over mixins to achieve reusability.

I want a component to emit events and to be stylable. So I have the mixins EventEmitter which contains functions to manipulate the events and Stylable which contains functions to manipulate the styling.

```
var Styleable = {
  addStyleProperty: function(styleProperty) {
     ...
  },
  ... 
};
var EventEmitter = {
   addEventListener: function(eventName, func) {
   },
   ...
};
```

With mixins an example component looks like the following:

```
var Button = React.createClass({
  mixins = [EventEmitter, Styleable],
  ...
});
```

With composition I tried to create components for Styleable and EventEmitter like this:

```
var StylableComponent = React.createClass({
  addStyleProperty: ...
  render: function() {
    React.createElement(this.props.wrappedComponent, ...)??
  }
}
var EventEmitterComponent = ...
```

But I don't know how to use them correctly. I read that I have to use these components as a wrapper, but I don't know how to achieve this. I tried to do it like in the render function of the above example. How can I instanciate a button that has the functions just like the mixin variant? So that I just pass the required functionalitys like this:

```
<Button is={[StyleableComponent, EventEmitterComponent]}/>
```

Or am I expecting a wrong behaviour from composition?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you want to create a function that returns a brand new component.

For your EventEmitter, for example, it'd look something like this:

```js
import eventEmitter from 'your-event-emitter-location';

// This function takes a component as an argument, and returns a component.
function eventEmitterWrapper(ComposedComponent) {
  // This is the brand new "wrapper" component we're creating:
  return class extends Component {
    render() {
      // We want to return the supplied component, with all of its supplied
      // props, but we also want to "add in" our additional behaviour.
      return (
        <ComposedComponent
          {...this.props}
          eventEmitter={eventEmitter}
        />
      );
    }
  }
}
```

To use it, you'd do something like this:

```js
import Button from '../Button';
import eventEmitterWrapper from '../../HOCs/event-emitter';

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    const EventEmitterButton = eventEmitterWrapper(Button);

    return (
      <div>
        <EventEmitterButton onClick={doSomething}>
          Hello there!
        </EventEmitterButton>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Finally, within your button, you'd have access to event emitter from the props:

```js
const Button = ({ children, onClick, eventEmitter }) => {
  // Let's say, for example, you want to emit an event whenever the
  // button is clicked. You could do something like this:
  const clickHandler = (ev) => {
    onClick(ev);
    
    if (eventEmitter) {
      eventEmitter.emit('click', ev);
    }
  };
  
  return (
    <button onClick={clickHandler}>
      {children}
    <button>
      
  )
}
```

**NOTE**: This is a contrived example. This pattern is a little smelly to me; The `Button` knows too much about the internal workings of the event emitter (It shouldn't need to know that it has an `emit` method, for example. If you change how your event emitter works, you'd have a bunch of "dumb" components to update).

To fix this smell, I'd need to know more about your use-case, but I'd likely make the class returned by the `eventEmitterWrapper` function expose simple, specific methods (such as "emitEvent", which would take a single argument of the mouse/keyboard event)

Hopefully it illustrates how to use higher-order-components though!

Additional reading:

- https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/13/mixins-considered-harmful.html
- https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e#.ktwwneyg5

Comment: I have read the given sources, that is why I tried to refactor it. It works just fine if there is one functionality I want to add, like EventEmitter. But if I want to add the Styleable also, I have a chain like `styleableWrapper` which then takes the already wrapped component which is smelly to me. I hope you get the point. I also don't have access to the functions declared in `eventEmitterWrapper` any longer.

Comment: Higher order components can wrap higher order components; it isn't smelly at all (it's just function composition!). I think as long as there isn't inter-dependencies... it gets a bit smelly if `styleableWrapper` depends on `eventEmitterWrapper`, but it doesn't sound like that's the case.

Comment: For your comment about not having access to functions declared in `eventEmitterWrapper`, they need to be passed down as props. Because each HOC is passing all delegated props down, anything you pass will be gathered by `{...this.props}`.